# How to change %20 to - using htaccess with this code and how to get that value in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello i am trying to change %20 to - using htaccess file but i am not being able to do it. Please have a look below code.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for index.php
RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L]

#Rewrite for inner.php?u=####
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)  inner.php?u=$1 [L]

#Rewrite for article.php?id=1&title=Title Goes Here (unlimited number of space can be here)
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)  article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and i am trying to get the value in article.php and echo the value using php like below

```
<?php echo $_GET['title'] ?>
```

The url looks like below. Their is %20 in the url but i want to convert it in -
http://localhost/learning/article/1/i%20am%20title

And when i try to echo the title value it only display i other are not shown. Please help me to fix it. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below .htaccess code. ([^/]+) REGEX code will allow all the chars in the querystring. So it will allow spaces and your querystring value will not broke down up to first space now.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for index.php
RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L]

#Rewrite for inner.php?u=####
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)  inner.php?u=$1 [L]

#Rewrite for article.php?id=1&title=Title Goes Here (unlimited number of space can be here)
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)  article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the answer but the problem is not fixed. The %20 are not converted to -

Comment: Use url_decode php function to convert ℅20 back to space after getting query string parameter value using $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

Apache automatically rewrites %20 into space (\s) but your rule doesn't accept it. This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

In your PHP code you will may need use urldecode(). However, I highly recommend to ignore title in GET parameter and to use only ID (don't forget to check if it is the right type (eg. integer)). Reading the title from your database is more secure.

Comment: @zdenek Thank you for the answer but the problem is not fixed. It is not converting %20 value -

Comment: Interesting. The third simple syntax doesn't work as well? Do you really need the title from URL? Title in URL is good for SEO, I understand, but I am not sure why you need to pass it into $_GET[title] variable? It is the security hole if you want to print the title on the page.

Comment: @zdenek I will need $_GET[] variable so that i can get the value and fetch the data from database which match the $_GET[] variable. I don't need $_GET[title] variable but i will need $_GET['id'] variable so that i can fetch the data from the database. Thank you for replying for my comment. :)

Comment: Ok, I have tried it and found the problem. Just add \s in your rule: ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)